# Fetching Authenticated Users list from Firebase in a dropdown list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Realtime Database while developing a app using Flutter. I want to display all the authenticated/registered users using a dropdown list, but I am unable to find any good resource for it .
Can anyone help me for it? Any lead would be very helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+get+list+of+users ?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this functionality in my app recently.

You should store user information in a Cloud Firestore collection on user signup and then retrieve the list of users from that collection.

While implementing above collection, set `userId` as the `documentId` as userId is unique.